# Adding Snapshot to the Test Case Level using Jasmine and TypeScript with Allure reporter

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, typescript2.0, allure

I am getting the error while using allure reporter with jasmine and typescript.

```
  jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(done => {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {              
                allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
                    return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
                }, 'image/png')();
        done();
            });
        });
```

Here as typescript check the type , so i am getting the below error for the line

```
jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(done => 

[ts] Argument of type '(done: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
(parameter) done: any
```

However, the same code works fine with Javascript and jasmine.

So please help how to have the same code work for typescript and jasmine